# React Jest snapshot tests fail when --coverage flag enabled

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, code-coverage, snapshot-testing

I have built a React app (v16.13.1) and am testing it with Jest (v25.1.0).  When I run `npm test` the tests all pass fine, but when I run `npm test -- --coverage` all of the components return `undefined` and all of the snapshot tests fail.

It's happening with every component in the app.  A typical example of a component exhibiting this behaviour is:

`src/components/Card.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Card = ({ title, subtitle, children }) => (
  <div className="card">
    {title && <div className="card-header">{title}</div>}
    <div className="card-body">
      {subtitle && <div className="small mb-3">{subtitle}</div>}
      <div className="mt-3">{children}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

Card.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  subtitle: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

Card.defaultProps = {
  title: null,
  subtitle: null
};

export default Card;
```

`src/components/Card.test.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import Card from './Card';

let tree;

describe('without title or subtitle', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    tree = renderer.create(
      <Card>
        <p>Hello there</p>
      </Card>
    );
  });

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});

describe('with title and subtitle', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    tree = renderer.create(
      <Card title="Test" subtitle="This is a test">
        <p>Hello there</p>
      </Card>
    );
  });

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

These tests all used to pass just fine but now they are failing but only when the `coverage` flag is enabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide more detail than *"failing"*?

Comment: The components return `undefined` and so the snapshot does not match, but only when the `--coverage` flag is enabled

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen this before: For stateless components, you may need to define displayName prop. 
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1824#issuecomment-250478026

Comment: This is the same issue as posted on git (ie loses name = `undefined`)

Comment: I added `displayName` for each component and it made no difference.